# CSS HTML Font size as per PSD design

Tags: html, css, psd

How to use exact font size in html as per psd design. example in psd font size is 14pt what font size can be use in 'px' for html/css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty broad question here but you can see font sizes here: http://home.earthlink.net/~silvermaplesoft/standards/size_type.html

14pt font is *roughly* 20px however you will notice its not perfect.